# Definition of integral in the context of measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\left( X, \mathcal{F}, \mu \right)$ be a measure space. I want to make sense to the integral $$\int_{X}f(x)d\mu (x).$$
It's easy to give meaning to this when $f$ is a simple function. But if $f$ is not simple, the first idea is to approximate $f$ by simple functions such that
$$\int_{x}f(x)d\mu(x) = \lim_{n}\int_{X}f_{n}(x)d\mu(x).\qquad (1)$$
The problem is, that not all functions can be approximated by simple functions, why we need measureable functions which are those functions that **can** be approximated by simple functions. So the author gives the following definition (when $f$ is non-negative)
$$\int_{X}f(x)d\mu(x) = \sup_{\phi}\int_{X}\phi(x)d\mu(x) \qquad (2),$$
where the supremum is taken over the class of simple functions $\phi$ such that $0\leq \phi \leq f$.

So if every measureable function can be approximated by simple functions why do we need (2); couldn't we just use (1) always ?

I'm also confused since another author writes the following

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definition (2) says exactly what the integral is; the right-hand side is perfectly well defined. There are problems with trying to use (1) as a *definition*. First you need to specify in what sense the simple functions $f_n$ "approximate" $f$. And *then* you need to show that $\lim\int f_n\,d\mu$ *exists*.

Note that, for example, if you just assume that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for every $x$ it does not even *follow* that the limit of the integrals exists. So whatever sort of approximation you have in mind for (1) it has to be something other than pointwise convergence...

Comment: Another problem is that for a given function $f$, there can be two different sequences $f_n, g_n$ of simple functions, such that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ and $g_n(x) \to f(x)$ for every $x$, and $\lim \int f_n, \lim \int g_n$ both exist, but are different. Which of the limits is the "right" value for $\int f$?

Comment: @NateEldredge I considered mentioning that, decided it's not really "another" problem, rather just an example of how the problem I mentioned might arise - the limit of the sequence that alternates between $\int f_n$ and $\int g_n$ does not exist. Hmm, that's mathematically speaking - could be pedagogically you raise an excellent point.

Comment: See my updated question.

Comment: See my non-updated answer! The author doesn't just use a bare (1) for the definition, he specifies carefully that he's talking about a _non-decreasing_ sequence $f_n$. And he mentions (after the purported definition, when he really should say so before saying he's defined anything) that the answer is the same for any two such approximations. Presumably he proves this at some point...

Comment: @NateEldredge Just realized, based on the "update", that what you mentioned really _is_ "another" problem. At least for some notions of approximation; if we're talking about approximation by an increasing sequence then what I said about this really being that is simply wrong.